# freopen() not able to write to a file?

Tags: c++, file-io, sublimetext3, sublimetext, freopen

On MacOSX, I'm trying to read input from inp.txt and write output to outp.txt on Sublime.
I'm redirecting stdout to outp.txt

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    // for getting input from input.txt
    freopen("inp.txt", "r", stdin);
    // for writing output to output.txt
    freopen("outp.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n+1;
}
```

Error is

```
ld: can't open output file for writing: /Users/sarath/Documents/code, errno=21 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Finished in 2.9s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "/Users/sarath/Documents/code.cpp" -o "/Users/sarath/Documents/code" && "/Users/sarath/Documents/code"]
[dir: /Users/sarath/Documents]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Why it is failing and please help ?
ThankYou.

Comment: The error is from your linker not the application itself.  Not sure about MacOS but on Linux an errno value of 21 corresponds to `EISDIR`.  That implies your intended output file `/Users/sarath/Documents/code` already exists but is a directory.

Comment: Rename your "code.cpp"  file so that the part before ".cpp" is not already the name of something in the Documents folder.

Comment: ThankYou very much , it is because of duplicate file and directory names.